# Is there a way to obtain a Configuration object from a configuration file in the isolated storage?

Tags: wpf, isolatedstorage, configurationmanager

Is there a way to obtain a Configuration object from a configuration file in the isolated storage?

I'm storing a several configuration files in my app's IsolatedStorage and i need to be able to retrieve the configuration sections within those files.

The problem is that the ConfigurationManager only accepts a path and i can't obtain the absolute path of a file within the isolated storage.

Is there a way to obtain a Configuration object from a configuration file in the isolated storage?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you get the absolute path to the files in Isolated Storage? Take a look at the [Can I get a path for a IsolatedStorage file and read it from external applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112681/can-i-get-a-path-for-a-isolatedstorage-file-and-read-it-from-external-applicatio) post to find out how you *can* do this.

If that doesn't work for you, take a look at the [IsolatedStorageFile Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) page at MSDN which features examples of manipulating files in IsolatedStorage.

Comment: the first option works. but it is using reflaction and it doesnt suite my need.  as i say configurationmanager accepts only absolute path. Is there any way that from IsolatedStorageFile class method i can get absolute path to file in isolated storage? thanks for your replay.

Comment: I don't think so, but you could just open the configuration file using the `IsolatedStorageFile` class and then extract the configuration object that way, can't you?