# Can I add database queries in my AudioPlayer class? wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to populate my background player playlist with tracks saved in database table.
How can i do that in my windows phone 8 app?

Answer (score 0):

The BackgroundAudioPlayer can only play files from isolated storage or from a remote URI. All you need to do is to have a list of audio tracks as playlist for the player.

These are only sample examples modify as per your need.

//get the uri to tracks using IsolatedStorageFileStream Name property of file.
 [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13274033/962545)

```
 private static string GetAbsolutePath(string filename)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        string absoulutePath = null;

        if (isoStore.FileExists(filename))
        {
            IsolatedStorageFileStream output = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, isoStore);
            absoulutePath = output.Name;

            output.Close();
            output = null;
        }

        return absoulutePath;
    }

    //now instantiate list of audio track with the uri to track
    List<AudioTrack>  = new List<AudioTrack>
    {
        new AudioTrack(new Uri("URI TO FILE IN ISOLATED STORAGE", UriKind.Relative), 
                "title",
                "artist",
                "album",
                "Uri To albumArt or null"),

        new AudioTrack(new Uri("URI TO FILE IN ISOLATED STORAGE", UriKind.Relative), 
                "title",
                "artist",
                "album",
                "Uri To albumArt or null")
    };
```

For further reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx